# Can't add default gateway in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux

I'm trying to put a Windows and Kali Linux machine on the same network. I used

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.3 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

which worked fine but when I use

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.10.1
```

it says `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

Comment: What is the significance of the Windows machine? Don't you have a DHCP server that gives you your IP and gateway?

Comment: The windows machine is just a basic windows 10 machine

Comment: Normally, adding an IP address to eth0 should also create a route to the corresponding subnet. It is odd that this did not happen here. Please add the output of `ip a` and `ip r` to your question.

Comment: Prefer using the new `ip` commands instead of `ifconfig`, as they will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can

```
ping 192.168.10.1
```

then try

```
route add default gw 192.168.10.1  eth0
```

where eth0 is the internet interface on the Kali machine.

If you can't ping 192.168.10.1 then there is no router at that address.

Comment: It's possible that a router is configured to not answer to pings, or that it's so overworked that it does not have time to answer to pings. But try with `arping` instead: a router *must* answer to ARP requests, or else it's not useful at all (without a very special setup, at least). If `arping` is not installed, use `ip neigh show` or `arp -a` to see if your ping attempt gave you the MAC address of the router or not: if it did, that proves the router exists even if it does not answer to pings.

Comment: That is not OP's problem. The error is "**network** unreachable", although it should be reachable after setting the IP address on eth0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the iproute2 command:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.10.1/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: When I do this I get the Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length